# iOS background uploads - how to verify responses received if app crashes?

Tags: ios, upload, nsurlsession, nsurlsessionuploadtask

When performing background uploads in iOS, is there a mechanism in place that will re-deliver upload results from the system if the app crashes while handling said results?  I was hoping to see some sort of confirmation system in place telling the OS that the app has finished processing all of the data it was sent, etc but I do not see something like this in the documentation.

What I am worried about is that my users will upload 100 items and once these are all uploaded in the background my app will launch (in background mode), allowing me to handle the responses. If the app crashes while processing the response data, the other unprocessed response data is forever lost now.

This is of course an issue when doing uploads in the app as well - if you upload something and crash while handling the response you'd lose *that* upload (and any other uploads in flight at the time), but you risk losing way too much data in the background IMO.

Comment: there is no way to say iOS that your app done to upload. The way you can do is to make something on server side to check if app done upload. if app was crashed or iOS kill it for some reason, you can send silent push to wake up app and continue upload in background.

Comment: There _could_ be though, right? iOS could inform you that background session delegate calls are about to start being delivered, they deliver them, and then they inform you that background session delegate calls are over, which would require you to reply with a boolean indicating you confirm delivery/etc.  I see nothing like this right now, but wanted to ask to make sure!

Answer (score 0):

For an upload task in a background session, as soon as you reconnect to the existing session by “creating” a session with the same session name, your app should get delegate calls just as though it were still running from before.

Obviously you will have to persist any app-specific data structures that tie the task’s identifier and session name to the specific content you’re uploading, since anything previously in memory is obviously gone at that point.

Comment: Yes, of course.  My question regarding this is, "what if you crash while handling the delegate calls"? That is potentially a lot of data lost, if iOS does not give you a chance to handle the delegate calls again.

Comment: Ah.  I understand.  If you're concerned about that, the best thing to do is to use a download task with a request body.  Then, move the file immediately, and if you crash while processing it, you can try again on relaunch.